# Access to Font at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: firefox, cors

Just recently I noticed that a customers website I developed was not showing some external resources with firefox...
I checked under Chrome and there the resources show, but both browser do show a error in the console, though different ones.

I am so far that I understand it's a CORS issue, but I don't understand how to fix it.
On the CDN I have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin completely opened, but as the error in Chrome states, the problem seems to be more an issue that the origin sends the header without www while it sends the request from a www domain...
Do I need to set a header to a www domain???

Isn't this overengineering of security?

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2|svg|css|font.css|jpg|png|gif|js)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Firefox:

> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Gotham-Book"
>   style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:3):
>   status=2147500036 source: 'external CDN domain'

Chrome:

> Access to Font at 'external CDN domain' from origin 'www domain' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   has a value 'domain com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'www domain com' is therefore not allowed access.